# Scope declaration in model not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm using Ruby on Rails 3 and I created a few scopes in my object class but when I call them from within my code it returns  an error:

> irb>Transaction.first.committed
>
> => undefined method `commited' for #

object class:

> class Transaction < ActiveRecord::Base
>
> ```
>  attr_accessible :amount, :description, :published, :task_description_id, :discrete_task_id, :transaction_type
>
>  belongs_to :discrete_task
>
>  scope :committed, where(:transaction_type => "committed")
>
>  scope :obligated, where(:transaction_type => "obligated")
>
>  scope :expensed, where(:transaction_type => "expensed")
> ```
>
> end

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't call a scope (a class method) on a single Transaction object (an instance).

You would have to do this:

```
Transaction.committed
```

You get back an `ActiveRelation` (essentially an `Array`, but you can call other scopes on it).

What would you expect `Transaction.first.committed` to do, anyways? You'd have a single object, and then you'd try to find where its `transaction_type` is "committed". You already have the object, so you would call its `#transaction_type` method.

A scope would bring back *all* Transaction objects that have a transaction type of committed. If you want an *instance* method that tells you if a *single* object is committed, then you'd have to make an instance method like:

```
def committed?
  transaction_type == "committed"
end
```

Then you could write:

```
Transaction.first.committed? # => true
```

Answer (score 0):

`Transaction.first` will return a `Transaction` object so you can't call `where` on it. Try:

```
Transaction.committed.first
```